# What made this tiny honeycomb-like structure?

Tags: entomology

[image: tiny honeycomb-like structure wrapped around twig]

I found this on the ground in Maryland.  I believe the twig is from a tulip poplar tree.  The structure looks like a tiny honeycomb except that the cells are individual tubes rather than a true hexagonal honeycomb shape.  It's one layer deep and wraps completely around the branch.  I assume it was made by some tiny insect, but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many insects lay eggs in tight clusters; because of the shape of the eggs (like honeycomb cells themselves), the cluster looks a bit like a honeycomb.  If you had a high quality macro shot, the eggs might be easier to identify definitively.

Newly hatched Beet Armyworms:

[image]

Wheel Bug (Arilus cristatus) Eggs:

[image]

> Wheel bugs are common in eastern North America, but are confirmed to occupy areas of Mexico and Guatemala.

With wheel bug for size:

[image]

My guess is that you found a cluster of Wheel Bug eggs.

> Females lay eggs at a low elevation on trees, bushes, twigs, and other objects.[5] Secreted glue serves as an adhesive which maintains the cluster formation of the eggs. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_bug)